# Rendering gsp transform self-closing tags into empty tags

Tags: xml, grails, gsp

I'm rendering an XML using gsp templates, everything works fine but self-closing tags are transformed into empty tags. For example, if my template has the following tag:

```
<Custom:tag />
```

when I render in the contoller:

```
String xml = g.render template:template, model: model
```

the `xml` variable value is

```
<Custom:tag></Custom:tag>
```

It's still a valid xml, but when I try to send to the server, where I have no control, I get validation errors because of the `Custom:tag`.

How can I prevent Grails parsing this tags?

Comment: Grails have a good API to render XML, so templates is not the best way to do it. Have you [tried it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)?

Comment: you should really use the supercool groovy xml builder, what youre doing is a mess

Comment: I considered using templates because I want to support many XML but [Groovy XML Builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy's+MarkupBuilder) is definitively the best option.

Answer (score 1):

here you have a simple example how you can easily render xml

```
    def renderXml() {

        render(contentType: 'text/xml') {
            startTag(version: '1.2', state:'FeelGood') {
                childTag(value:"this is a value")
                nestingFun(howmuchisthefish:"42"){
                    childTag(value:"this is a value")
                    childTag(value:"this is a value")
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

this will result in something similiar like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <startTag version="1.2" state="feelGood">
      <childTag>"this is a value"</childTag>
      <nestingFun howmuchisthefish="42" >
          <childTag>"this is a value"</childTag>
          <childTag>"this is a value"</childTag>
      </nestingFun>
 </startTag>
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment! I couldn't render self-closed tag but after reading your comment I got the answer: selfClosedTag ()